# "Authentication failed" error when accessing blob through SAS URI

Tags: azure, next.js, azure-blob-storage

I me and my team are developing a web app using NextJS, and recently we've been implementing Azure Blob Storage for file upload and display.
I am currently working on Image display for the frontend. for doing so, I am generating a SAS token with ***generateBlobSASQueryParameters*** function with a sasOptions object that contains the following parameters:

- container name
- blob name
- startsOn (date object)
- expiresOn (date object)
- permissions: BlobSASPermissions.parse("racwdt")

after that, im generating a SAS URI, using the specified blob name and the newly generated SAS token. however, when im trying to access the sas URI, im met with an error:

> Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of
> Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
> RequestId:SOME_REQUEST_ID
> Time:2022-10-03T13:49:24.2788454Z
> Signature fields not well formed.
> **The signature:**

```
https://mystorageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/images/example.png?sv=2021-06-08&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupiytfx&se=2022-11-22T20:45:23Z&st=2022-10-03T11:45:23Z&spr=https&sig=ECjnJEvZCOPhvuOgCsGBMIwone7VmsiJQopVNyb4yB0%3D?sv=2021-06-08&st=2022-10-06T06%3A24%3A12Z&se=2022-10-06T06%3A34%3A12Z&sr=b&sp=racwdt&sig=ioMMCIFo0eXC%2BTZ9yDZB9D5JHz%2F%2BUyMMFqTPEG0QSqg%3D
```

Following are the parameters for a URL that is failing to authenticate:

```
sv=2021-06-08
ss=bfqt
srt=sco
sp=rwdlacupiytfx
se=2022-11-22T20:45:23Z
st=2022-10-03T11:45:23Z
spr=https
sig=ECjnJEvZCOPhvuOgCsGBMIwone7VmsiJQop
```

**Is there anything I can do or look after when generating a SAS URI to make it work?**

Note: When manually generating a SAS URL by clicking on the "Generate SAS token and URL" button on the blob, I can access the image by copying it to the url field in my browser

Comment: Please edit your question and include the SAS token which is giving you the problem.

Comment: Looking at the SAS URL, it seems you are duplicating the SAS token (look at `?sv=` in the SAS URL). Please check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Gaurav_Mantri suggested, **the SAS token appeared TWICE in the SAS URL I got.**

The code that made that faulty URL:

```
 const sasToken = generateBlobSASQueryParameters(
      sasOptions,
      sharedKeyCredential
    ).toString();

    const blobSasUri = `${
    containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName).url
    }?${sasToken}`;
```

It appears to me That i've generated a SAS token for a specific blob, then by getting its url using

> containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName).url

I've already got the **FULL** blob URL (with the SAS token already in it).
Afterwards, i've concatinated the generated SAS URL again, therefore got a faulty URL.

### **Fix:**

```
const sasToken = generateBlobSASQueryParameters(
  sasOptions,
  sharedKeyCredential
).toString(); // For generating the SAS token

const blobURL = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blobName).url;
// Afterwards, getting the full blob URL (with the new SAS token already concatinated to it)
```